# List to dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I have this type of list that I'm trying to convert it to a dictionary, but the key are repeating and I'm not being able to do so....

The list is like this:

```
my_list = [['full name ',
  ' Arthur Schopenhauer',
  'date of birth ',
  ' Friday, February 22, 1788 (232 years ago)',
  'place of birth ',
  ' Gdansk, Pomorskie, Poland',
  'date of death ',
  ' Friday, September 21, 1860 (age: 72 years) ',
  'place of death ',
  ' Frankfurt, Hesse, Germany'],
 ['full name ',
  ' Aristotle',
  'date of birth ',
  ' 384 BC (2403 years ago)',
  'place of birth ',
  ' Halkidiki, Macedonia Central, Greece',
  'date of death ',
  ' 322 BC (age: 62 years) ',
  'place of death ',
  ' Evvoia, Greece Central, Greece']]
```

Im Trying to get something like:

```
my_dict = {"full name": ['Arthur Schopenhauer', 'Aristotle'],
 "date of birth": [' Friday, February 22, 1788 (232 years ago)', '384 BC (2403 years ago)'],
 "place of birth": [...],
 "date of death": [...],
 "place of death": [...]}
```

Could you help me with some tips or opinions?

Comment: `dict(zip(my_list[::2], my_list[1::2]))`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget that won't work because `my_list` is a list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `defaultdict` with a list type as value, then read each list by pair (key, value) and add the `value` to the `list` given by the `key`

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for values in my_list:
    for k, v in zip(values[::2], values[1::2]):
        result[k].append(v)

print(result)
```

Giving

```
{
    "full name ": [
        " Arthur Schopenhauer",
        " Aristotle"
    ],
    "date of birth ": [
        " Friday, February 22, 1788 (232 years ago)",
        " 384 BC (2403 years ago)"
    ],
    "place of birth ": [
        " Gdansk, Pomorskie, Poland",
        " Halkidiki, Macedonia Central, Greece"
    ],
    "date of death ": [
        " Friday, September 21, 1860 (age: 72 years) ",
        " 322 BC (age: 62 years) "
    ],
    "place of death ": [
        " Frankfurt, Hesse, Germany",
        " Evvoia, Greece Central, Greece"
    ]
}
```